# Diff consecutive lines unix

Tags: linux, unix, binary-tree, diff

I have a tree in flattened out lines like :

```
a<1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=1
a<1 and b>1 and d<1 then result=2
a<1 and b>1 and d>1 then result=3
```

I want to print remove the substring of each consecutive line that matches with the previous line
For example, result would be :

```
a<1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=1
        b>1 and d<1 then result=2
                d>1 then result=3
```

Essentially, the common element between the previous line and the current line are not printed again -> only the differences between two lines are printed.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Has to be in shell? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative, using fields as unit of match, with final output formatting

```
awk 'NR==1{w=length($0)} 
     {sep=line=""; 
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if(p[i]!=$i) 
          for(j=i;j<=NF;j++) {
             p[j]=$j; 
             line=line sep $j;
             sep=OFS
          } 
         printf "%"w"s\n", line
      }' diffs

a<1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=1
        b>1 and d<1 then result=2
                d>1 then result=3
```

Comment: The choice of first line for the width leads to some interesting formatting on extended versions of the data (I'd be tempted to use `w=length($0)` on each line), but otherwise what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes, this assumes the root of the "tree" is the first line.  Perhaps a pre scan the file to get the max length is a better solution.

Comment: I ran your code on a longer test file with some double-digit results.  It produced some interesting alignments with the code — only out by one character since my line lengths only varied that much.

Comment: The additional data I used was: `a=1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=4
a=1 and b=1 and c=1 then result=5
a=1 and b=1 and c>1 then result=6
a=1 and b>1 and c<1 then result=7
a=1 and b>1 and c=1 then result=8
a=1 and b>1 and c>1 then result=9
a>1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=10
a>1 and b<1 and c=1 then result=11
a>1 and b<1 and c>1 then result=12
a>1 and b=1 and c<1 then result=13
a>1 and b=1 and c=1 then result=14
a>1 and b=1 and c>1 then result=15
a>1 and b>1 and c<1 then result=16
a>1 and b>1 and c=1 then result=0
a>1 and b>1 and c>1 then result=22`. You could vary some of the results as 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=length($0); i++) 
    if (substr($0,i,1)!=substr(a,i,1)) {printf "%s",substr($0,i,1);a=""}
      else printf " ";
    printf "\n"
    a=$0}'
```

yields

```
a<1 and b<1 and c<1 then result=1
         >1 and d<1 then result=2
                 >1 then result=3
```

i.e. common characters between the previous line and the current line are not printed again

If you need your posted result, you could split your line to form tokens and compare those tokens with the tokens of the previous line. You would the either print the token or the necessary spaces to get the identation.

Comment: It's not entirely clear that you should drop the `b` from the second line or the `d` from the third line; that's a bit too enthusiastic, I think.

Comment: Therefore i wrote the text under the result. It fits for the request to remove matching substring from previous line, but not the example. That's why i mentioned the token based method, which i did not elaborate...